# How to find particular interface name and status from ifconfig command?

Tags: grep, command-line-interface, ifconfig

When I use `ifconfig` command, it will show the details of all active devices.

I want the interface name only, and want to check whether the interface is running or not.

```
ifconfig | grep interface-name
```

This will give all detail about the interface but I want to print only interface name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have the interface name, you can do the following:

```
$ ifconfig interface-name &> /dev/null
$ echo $?
```

If the output is 0, the interface exists, otherwise, it doesn't.

Comment: thank you,I got your answer but I want to print interface-name

Comment: @yashshah You already have it no? Check if `$?` is 0, then simply print it.

Answer (score 0):

To see (only) Interface Name, IF Name, you could try these commands in the Terminal (from [name of my Network Interface?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/188377/how-can-i-find-the-name-of-my-network-interface)):

`ip route list | grep default | awk '{print $5} '` This is for the default route.
or
`ls /sys/class/net` This is for all names.